# let user download pdf by converting html information into pdf

Tags: python, pdf, flask, datatables, xhtml2pdf

I have informations which pops up in fancybox, e.g. a user form(which includes images, his/her address, phone no, name etc..), now how can I convert that into PDF and let user download pdf file. Can this be achieved using jquery.

I use datatables to show rows of user informations, which when clicked in individual rows are popped up in fancybox. There is a plugin in datatables called datatools which lets user to convert table into csv, xls, pdf file, which uses 'swf' file. Is there some way to convert html rendered page to pdf ??

I am using python2.7, flask

Comment: i think your best bet here is going to be to have a Postscript template for the form you want to generate, insert the values you want into that template, and generate a PDF from that with Ghostscript, then send that to the user.

Comment: There's [Flask-WeasyPrint](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-WeasyPrint/) extension, which can render the template as PDF.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert HTML to PDF using [WKHTML2PDF](https://wkhtmltopdf.org).